# Why I get 500 Internal error when I scan my sites by Ssl Labs API? I use php

Tags: ssl

I get Internal Error every time, when I try to get/scan my sites by API.
I get the correct answer, every time, when I try to scan my site in the browser by this url:
URL : https://api.dev.ssllabs.com/api/v2/analyze?host=xxx&publish=off&startNew=on&fromCache=off&ignoreMismatch=off

But I get Internal error all the time, if try to use the scan api in my php code.
*** If I scan one of my sites in browser then in my php code, I get the correct answer. I think
"startNew" doesn't work, when I use scan in my php code.

Steps(1):

1. call api :
   https://api.dev.ssllabs.com/api/v3/analyze?host=xxxxxxx&publish=off&startNew=on&fromCache=off&ignoreMismatch=off

   2. wait 90 sec
   3. call api :
      https://api.dev.ssllabs.com/api/v3/analyze?host=xxxxxxx&publish=off&startNew=off&fromCache=on&ignoreMismatch=off
   4. I get internal Error

Steps (2):

1. [Browser] call api : https://api.dev.ssllabs.com/api/v3/analyze?host=xxxxxxx&publish=off&startNew=on&fromCache=off&ignoreMismatch=off
2. [PHP Code] : call api : https://api.dev.ssllabs.com/api/v3/analyze?host=xxxxxxx&publish=off&startNew=on&fromCache=off&ignoreMismatch=off
3. wait 90 sec
4. call api : https://api.dev.ssllabs.com/api/v3/analyze?host=xxxxxxx&publish=off&startNew=off&fromCache=on&ignoreMismatch=off
5. I get correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and I made my own API request library. If you want you can also use that.
https://github.com/parhamPudding/SslLabAPIV3-helper/tree/master